# get and filter data asynchronously

Tags: c#, api, linq, .net-4.0

I want to get some data from api as **Json**, then I have to deserialize it
to list of contacts using **JsonConvert** to list objects to compare with an another list that contains old contacts.

my problem is that I take some time to get data(about 2000 rows) and takes another time to filtering.
my question is can I do those 2 steps at the same time?.
for example start filtering as I start getting data. or for example filter as I git new 10 rows, I filter them.
I hope I have described my question currently.

Comment: Your question lacks sufficient detail for anyone to have a hope of answering it. We don't even know what format the data arrives in, how you're filtering it, etc.

Comment: @LIama, I added some description, can you check please.